# Office VBA - Failure in logic criteria for a Do Until Loop

Tags: excel, vba, logic

So, I am writing a VBA macro that will count the number of instances where by an employee is absent through sickness. An instance of sickness is defined as a period of contiguous workdays where the employee is recorded as being sick (so this obviously excludes weekends). You can view my source data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OU3vS--TZV6ej8R3VEu3S4RBQpTwUtdub1rI6vus1-4)

For some reason at run-time the logic is failing on this line:
`Do Until Cells(r, c).Value <> "Sick" And (Cells(4, c).Value <> "Sat" Or Cells(4, c).Value <> Sun")` and is therefore counting each Monday-sickness as a new instance. For example, Sheet "Rota" Row 10 has two instances of sick, but the macro will report four instances.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AbsenceInstances()

    Dim dtToday, dtStart As Date
    Dim r, c, dblTodayCol, dblStartCol, dblInstances, dblAgentRow As Double
    Dim rngFindRow As Range

    Sheets("Rota").Select

'    dtToday = Int(Now())
    dtToday = "31/12/2019"
'    dtStart = dtToday - 364
    dtStart = "31/12/2018"

    'define upper & lower boundaries of measurement area
    On Error GoTo NotFound
        dblTodayCol = WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(CDate(dtToday)), Sheets("Rota").Range("5:5"), 0)
        dblStartCol = WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(CDate(dtStart)), Sheets("Rota").Range("5:5"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo ContinueSub

NotFound:
    MsgBox "Please check that your data incorporates information back to " & dtStart & ", otherwise this function will not work.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub

ContinueSub:

    'loop through employee list to determine number of absences
    For r = 6 To 34
        For c = dblStartCol To dblTodayCol
            If Cells(r, c).Value = "Sick" Then
                ' an instance of sick is defined as contiguous days absence excluding weekends
                Do Until Cells(r, c).Value <> "Sick" And (Cells(4, c).Value <> "Sat" Or Cells(4, c).Value <> "Sun")
                    If Cells(4, c).Value = "Sat" Then c = c + 1
                    c = c + 1
                Loop
                dblInstances = dblInstances + 1
            End If
        Next c

    ' identify employee's data-row to output result
    Set rngFindRow = Sheets("Bradford scale").Range("A:A").Find(What:=Sheets("Rota").Range("B" & r).Value, _
                         After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                         LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not rngFindRow Is Nothing Then
        dblAgentRow = rngFindRow.Row
        Set rngFindRow = Nothing
    End If

    ' output result for employee
    Sheets("Bradford Scale").Cells(dblAgentRow, 5).Value = dblInstances

    ' reset for next employee
    dblInstances = 0

    Next r

    Sheets("Bradford Scale").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your criteria to:

```
Do Until Cells(r, c).Value <> "Sick" And Cells(4, c).Value <> "Sat" And Cells(4, c).Value <> "Sun"
```

You can't use `Or` combined with `Not` (in this case `<>`) that way. The value can never be
**Not(Sat) OR Not(Sun)** at the same time. But it can be **Not(Sat) AND Not(Sun)** - which is what you're after.

Comment: Thank you CLR, that nailed it.